# MySQL Database Doesn't Exist But MySQL Says It Does

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm trying to create a database called "loadboard". I am using PHPMyAdmin so I'm simply using the database wizard. When I enter "loadboard" into the database name field and submit it I get an error saying that the database already exists. The same error happens if I run a SQL command. When I go to my databases there is only one there and it is "information_schema". Why would MySQL think a database exists even though it doesn't? This is on a Linux server.

On a side note no matter what I try to name the database, it still belives it exists.

EDIT: I was able to get a database created using the name `schrödingers_cat`. It shows up, but then I tried to make one called `loadboard` again and I am getting the same error and it still does not show up.

Also if your going to downvote i'd appreciate some reasoning considering my problem is clearly outlined.

Comment: Downvote for what reason? My problem is clearly outlined.

Comment: Have you tried naming the database "`schrödingers_cat`" ?

Comment: Try to execute following sql command `show databases;` you can do this from PhpMyAdmin directly. Preferably from account with biggest privileges. Perhaps db exists, but current user cannot see it.

Comment: Executed the command and the only one that shows is "information_schema" and Spencer i can try lol but it's gonna give me the same result.

Comment: Actually Spencer that worked oddly enough.

Comment: If that worked, then that helps rule out permissions issues creating a directory in the msyql data directory. But for grins, you could do a `show variables like 'datadir'`, and then go to your MySQL server OS and check the directory. There should be a directory for each database that's been created. There should be a `mysql` directory for sure, containing myisam files. (We don't know if you're running on windows or linux.) Also, try running `select * from information_schema.schemata`. As another commenter suggested, the user your connected to MySQL as must have sufficient privileges.

Comment: localhost? shared host? vps?

Answer (score 1):

The user you are connecting as may not have permissions to view the existing `loadboard` database. Try connecting as `root`. You'll likely see it then.

Comment: how do i switch users? To my knowledge I am on the only account.

Comment: What username are you entering into the PhpMyAdmin login box? Try `root` instead of that user. Hopefully you know the root password.

Comment: I'm not. I login to my GoDaddy account and PHPMyAdmin doesn't ask for a password or user when I go to it.

Comment: Run this query: `select user();`. What does it return?

Comment: One user "cpses_jom5ChewTX@localhost"

Comment: Are there any other logins available for this account? What credentials do you use when you connect to it from code?

Comment: Odds are you have a `loadboard` database that was created by a user other than `cpses_jom5ChewTX@localhost` that has some permissions on this database.

Comment: I have a seperate username when I login from code, but even when I've tried running SQL from my code with those credentials it doesn't do anything just the same errors.

Comment: Right, because the database already exists. From your code, run a select query on a table in `loadboard`. Does it work?

Comment: if your on godaddy, dont create db's via phpmyadmin, create them via the control panel: https://nz.godaddy.com/help/create-mysql-databases-16016